Docker containers(safe-infrastructure) are exited on Ubuntu OS
I tried to deploy the safe-infrastructure on Ubuntu 22.04 using docker compose, but several docker containers were not running so I couldn't operate it.
It's working on my MacOS without any issues.
Here's some logs of one sub-docker containers(nginx-alpine):
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/06/29 06:28:10 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "cgw-web:3000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:47
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "cgw-web:3000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:47

Have you ever seen this issue? I cannot guess why it's not working on Ubuntu...
I appreciate your support, thank you!

Try:
docker compose pull
docker compose down -v
docker compose up


Thank you, looks like there's an environmental problem on the hosting server.
